# C++ performance, for versus while

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, while-loop

In general (or from your experience), is there difference in performance between for and while loops?

What if they are doubly/triply nested?

Is vectorization (SSE) affected by loop variant in g++ or Intel compilers?

Thank you

Comment: I'm glad you're only temporarily crippled. I am permanently, and I think it makes me a bit of a contrarian crank. I'm not only out-of-the-box, I can't get *in* the box. Anyway, if you do serious optimization as I try to show how, you may realize that things like this make a difference only at the very end stage of performance tuning. Good luck with your studies.

Comment: @Mike thanks.  sorry to hear about you.  sad thing is one takes many things for granted and then realizes how much important they are once you lose them :-(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here](http://www.linux-kongress.org/2009/slides/compiler_survey_felix_von_leitner.pdf) is a nice paper on the subject.

Comment: I think this paragraph sums it all up beautifully: "*Optimizing == important. But often: Readable code == more important.*"

I tend to favour `for` loops for iteration as it is clear where your loop variable is being initialised and incremented or decremented.

Answer (score 10):

Any intelligent compiler won't really show a difference between them. A `for` loop is really just syntactic sugar for a certain form of `while` loop, anyways.

Answer (score 2):

VS2015, Intel Xeon CPU

```
long long n = 1000000000;
int *v = new int[n];
int *v1 = new int[2*n];

start = clock();
for (long long i = 0, j=0; i < n; i++, j+=2)
    v[i] = v1[j];
end = clock();
std::cout << "for1 - CPU time = " << (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;

p = v; pe = p + n; p1 = v1;
start = clock();
while (p < pe)
{
    *p++ = *p1;
    p1 += 2;
}
end = clock();
std::cout << "while3 - CPU time = " << (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
```

for1 - CPU time = 4.055

while3 - CPU time = 1.271

Answer (score 1):

This is something easily ascertained by looking at disassembly.  For most loops, they will be the same assuming you do the same work.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10)
   ++i;
```

is the same as

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   ;
```

As for nesting, it really depends on how you configure it but same setups should yield same code.

Answer (score 1):

Should be zero difference, but do check as I've seen really crappy, older versions of GCC create different code ARM/Thumb code between the two.  One optimized away a compare after a subtract to set the zero flag where as the other did not.  Was very lame.

Nesting again should make no difference.  Not sure on SSE/Vectorization stuff, but again I'd expect there to be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

it should be negligible. an optimizing compiler should make the distinction nonexistent.