# In C/C++ Language... are for loop internally compile as While loop?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

In C/C++ Language... are `for` loops internally compiled as `while` loops?

Comment: Similar questions have been asked, such as what is the performance difference.  They are basically the same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879145/c-performance-for-versus-while/2879158#2879158

Comment: Not an exact duplicate. This asks about MS Visual C++ specifically, the other question seems to ask about g++/intel compilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, usually, basically. A for loop, written

```
for (a; b; c) { ... }
```

can be rewritten as

```
a;
while (b) { ...; c; }
```

Note that this doesn't take into account scoping and such issues, because when you translate a for to a while, scoping can't be written precisely in C++ syntax.

However, underneath, a for loop is really a series of statements and (conditional) gotos:

```
{
           a;
           goto test;

    body:  
           ...;
           c;

    test:
           if (b) goto body:
}
```

except that all of it is in assembly code.

Comment: Your loop could use more braces. `a`'s scope is in the loop, and I believe `c` is separated by some more braces.

Comment: @Pubby yes, I added a comment to that effect, I just realised that after reading another answer. But it's not really the same if you just add { } around them, because that would be creating two scopes, not just one which is how it really is. I don't think it can be written it properly.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can think of it like this:

given:

```
for (initialization; condition; updater) { body; }
```

It generates this analog:

```
{
  initialization;
  while (condition)
  {
     ... // body
     updater;
  }
}
```

But it's important to note a few things:

1. the initialization is part of the inner scope.  So if you declare a variable, it won't escape outside of the for loop.
2. the updater code cannot be skipped (except by breaking out of the for loop).  This  is unlike a while() loop where you can `continue` your way past your own update code.  I.e. you are responsible to ensure your updater is run or not - but the compiler enforces it for a for loop.

Comment: +1 for the contribution of point #2.  A subtle difference, but it's rarely of any importance to me.

Answer (score 2):

It is really up to your compiler on how the loops are generated into assembly. Generally speaking, if I were to manually code for loops by hand, they would look slightly different in the assembly. These optimizations are probably minor for your code, but you can save on perhaps extra load/stores if necessary. But it's most likely that your loop conditions (if they are counters) will all be arithmetic operations done in registers anyway.

To check your assembly (if you're using gcc/g++) try this:

`gcc -S -o your_asm_file.s your_src.c`

Then take a look inside the `*.s` file. That's exactly what your compiler is crunching down into machine code.

Answer (score 2):

Posting for completeness:

```
for (a; b; c) d;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
{
  a;
  while(b)
  {
    {
      d;
    }
    c;
  }
}
```